# Azure function - Endpoint doesn't work when 'routePrefix' is not empty

Tags: azure, azure-functions, fastapi

I have a fast-api application implemented as an azure function (serverless api). I'm trying to integrate it with azure static web app, but facing weird problem and can't solve it...

Function:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from backend.main import app


async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        return await func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle_async(req, context)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(str(e), status_code=200)
```

`app` is my fastapi application

My `host.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": 
  {
    "http": 
    {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

`function.json`:

```
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "{*route}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

When `routePrefix` is an empty string, it works. I can call fo example `http://localhost:7071/someEndpoint`

Whenever `routePrefix` has value, for example `api`, fastapi behaves as there is no such an endpoint. Example `http://localhost:7071/api/someEndpoint` will return

```
{
    "detail": "Not Found"
}
```

I have no idea why it happens... Maybe someone will advise.

Comment: Using FastAPI Framework with Azure Functions I am able to route to "/same" and "{*route}

Comment: Using FastAPI Framework, In a single Azure function (serverless API) it works in  __init__.py.

Comment: @kij89 did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Reference** :

> I was able `routePrefix` in  Azure function (serverless api)- Endpoint in **init**.py. I  have referred this git [@charris-msft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-fastapi-quickstart) ,[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-fastapi-app/) for  Integrate it with azure static web app.

I implemented  `from backend.main import app` which is working same as you.

```py
import  fastapi
app = fastapi.FastAPI()
@app.get("/same")
async  def  index():
return {
"info": "When using a parameterized route, try /hello/name.",
}
@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async  def  get_name(name: str):
return {
"name": name,
}
async  def  main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
"""Each request is redirected to the ASGI handler."""
return  await  func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle_async(req, context)
```

`**Log output**` :

[image]

**Respective Outputs With Different endpoints URL**

/{*route} :

[image]

**/same** :

[image]

**/hello/name** :

[image]

Comment: I think the issue is under azure static web app functions with fastapi, you need to add azure functions with python in azure static web app instead of create separate azure functions.

Comment: yes, Edward but kij89 is facing an issue with the local endpoint with functions with fastapi.  I will cross-check your point about the Azure static web app. Thank you